# What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?

Tags: regex

I am tired of always trying to guess, if I should escape special characters like '`()[]{}|`' etc. when using many implementations of regexps.

It is different with, for example, Python, sed, grep, awk, Perl, rename, Apache, find and so on.
Is there any rule set which tells when I should, and when I should not, escape special characters? Does it depend on the regexp type, like PCRE, POSIX or extended regexps?

Comment: Good regex libraries have functions like "`escape()`" to allow using arbitrary strings as regex parts.

Comment: You can use online Regex expression checkers like http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ (it's free). (Type in, then hover mouse over the regex you typed in)

Comment: In PHP you can use http://php.net/preg_quote

Comment: Escape all non-alphanumeric characters. period.

Comment: This question has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Other".

Comment: This question has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Escape Sequences".

Comment: see also `\Q`...`\E` escaping. `\Qhello?\E` matches "hello?" but not "hell" or "hello". Works in at least PCRE/PHP/Perl/Go

Comment: what about single, double quotes and "/" how do escape those in BRE and ERE syntax (outside character class)?

Answer (score 439, accepted):

Which characters you must and which you mustn't escape indeed depends on the regex flavor you're working with.

For PCRE, and most other so-called Perl-compatible flavors, escape these outside character classes:

```
.^$*+?()[{\|
```

and these inside character classes:

```
^-]\
```

For POSIX extended regexes (ERE), escape these outside character classes (same as PCRE):

```
.^$*+?()[{\|
```

Escaping any other characters is an error with POSIX ERE.

Inside character classes, the backslash is a literal character in POSIX regular expressions.  You cannot use it to escape anything.  You have to use "clever placement" if you want to include character class metacharacters as literals.  Put the ^ anywhere except at the start, the ] at the start, and the - at the start or the end of the character class to match these literally, e.g.:

```
[]^-]
```

In POSIX basic regular expressions (BRE), these are metacharacters that you need to escape to suppress their meaning:

```
.^$*[\
```

Escaping parentheses and curly brackets in BREs gives them the special meaning their unescaped versions have in EREs.  Some implementations (e.g. GNU) also give special meaning to other characters when escaped, such as \? and +.  Escaping a character other than .^$*(){} is normally an error with BREs.

Inside character classes, BREs follow the same rule as EREs.

If all this makes your head spin, grab a copy of [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com).  On the Create tab, click Insert Token, and then Literal.  RegexBuddy will add escapes as needed.

Comment: `/` is not a metacharacter in any of the regular expression flavors I mentioned, so the regular expression syntax does not require escaping it.  When a regular expression is quoted as a literal in a programming language, then the string or regex formatting rules of that language may require `/` or `"` or `'` to be escaped, and may even require `\\` to be doubly escaped.

Comment: what about colon, ":"? Shall it be escaped inside character classes as well as outside? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions says "PCRE has consistent escaping rules: any non-alpha-numeric character may be escaped to mean its literal value [...]"

Comment: MAY be escaped is not the same as SHOULD be escaped.  The PCRE syntax never requires a literal colon to be escaped, so escaping literal colons only makes your regex harder to read.

Comment: For non-POSIX ERE (the one I use most often because it's what's implemented by Tcl) escaping other things don't generate errors.

Comment: **For JavaScript developers**: `const escapePCRE = string => string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&");` from [Mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: For Java Developers: `someString.replaceAll("([.^$*+?()\\[{\\\\|])", "\\\\$1");`

Answer (score 85):

### Modern RegEx Flavors (PCRE)

<sup>Includes C, C++, Delphi, EditPad, Java, JavaScript, Perl, PHP (preg), PostgreSQL, PowerGREP, PowerShell, Python, REALbasic, Real Studio, Ruby, TCL, VB.Net, VBScript, wxWidgets, XML Schema, Xojo, XRegExp.
PCRE compatibility may vary</sup>

Anywhere: `. ^ $ * + - ? ( ) [ ] { } \ |`

---

### Legacy RegEx Flavors (BRE/ERE)

<sup>Includes awk, ed, egrep, emacs, GNUlib, grep, PHP (ereg), MySQL, Oracle, R, sed.
PCRE support may be enabled in later versions or by using extensions</sup>

**ERE/awk/egrep/emacs**

Outside a character class: `. ^ $ * + ? ( ) [ { } \ |`
    Inside a character class: `^ - [ ]`

**BRE/ed/grep/sed**

Outside a character class: `. ^ $ * [ \`
    Inside a character class: `^ - [ ]`
    For literals, don't escape: `+ ? ( ) { } |`
    For standard regex behavior, escape: `\+ \? \( \) \{ \} \|`

---

### Notes

- If unsure about a specific character, it can be escaped like `\xFF`
- Alphanumeric characters cannot be escaped with a backslash
- Arbitrary symbols can be escaped with a backslash in PCRE, but not BRE/ERE (they must only be escaped when required). For PCRE `] -` only need escaping within a character class, but I kept them in a single list for simplicity
- Quoted expression strings must also have the surrounding quote characters escaped, and often with backslashes doubled-up (like `"(\")(/)(\\.)"` versus `/(")(\/)(\.)/` in JavaScript)
- Aside from escapes, different regex implementations may support different modifiers, character classes, anchors, quantifiers, and other features. For more details, check out [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), or use [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to test your expressions live

Comment: There are many errors in your answer, including but not limited to:  None of your "modern" flavors require `-` or `]` to be escaped outside character classes.  POSIX (BRE/ERE) doesn't have an escape character inside character classes.  The regex flavor in Delphi's RTL is actually based on PCRE.  Python, Ruby, and XML have their own flavors that are closer to PCRE than to the POSIX flavors.

Comment: @JanGoyvaerts Thanks for the correction. The flavors you mentioned are indeed closer to PCRE. As for the escapes, I kept them that way for simplicity; it's easier to remember just to escape everywhere than a few exceptions. Power users will know what's up, if they want to avoid a few backslashes. Anyway, I updated my answer with a few clarifications that hopefully address some of this stuff.

Comment: I have been trying to find this for days! You are the BEST!

Comment: Do you need to scape "\" inside a character class as well?

Comment: Also what about single, double quotes and "/"? How do you get the literal values of them in BRE and ERE syntax?

Comment: @Caterina You can escape slashes with a backslash. Regex doesn't need quotes to be escaped. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 23):

Unfortunately there really isn't a set set of escape codes since it varies based on the language you are using.

However, keeping a page like the [Regular Expression Tools Page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tools.html) or this [Regular Expression Cheatsheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/) can go a long way to help you quickly filter things out.

Comment: The Addedbytes cheat sheet is grossly oversimplified, and has some glaring errors.  For example, it says `\<` and `\>` are word boundaries, which is true only (AFAIK) in the Boost regex library.  But elsewhere it says `<` and `>` are metacharacters and must be escaped (to `\<` and `\>`) to match them literally, which not true in any flavor

Answer (score 7):

POSIX recognizes multiple variations on regular expressions - basic regular expressions (BRE) and extended regular expressions (ERE).  And even then, there are quirks because of the historical implementations of the utilities standardized by POSIX.

There isn't a simple rule for when to use which notation, or even which notation a given command uses.

Check out Jeff Friedl's [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://regex.info/) book.

Answer (score 5):

Really, there isn't.  there are about a half-zillion different regex syntaxes; they seem to come down to Perl, EMACS/GNU, and AT&T in general, but I'm always getting surprised too.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, the meaning of things like ( and \( are swapped between Emacs style regular expressions and most other styles.  So if you try to escape these you may be doing the opposite of what you want.

So you really have to know what style you are trying to quote.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes simple escaping is not possible with the characters you've listed. For example, using a backslash to escape a bracket isn't going to work in the left hand side of a substitution string in sed, namely

```
sed -e 's/foo\(bar/something_else/'
```

I tend to just use a simple character class definition instead, so the above expression becomes

```
sed -e 's/foo[(]bar/something_else/'
```

which I find works for most regexp implementations.

BTW Character classes are pretty vanilla regexp components so they tend to work in most situations where you need escaped characters in regexps.

**Edit:** After the comment below, just thought I'd mention the fact that you also have to consider the difference between finite state automata and non-finite state automata when looking at the behaviour of regexp evaluation.

You might like to look at "the shiny ball book" aka Effective Perl ([sanitised Amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201419750)), specifically the chapter on regular expressions, to get a feel for then difference in regexp engine evaluation types.

Not all the world's a PCRE!

Anyway, regexp's are so clunky compared to [SNOBOL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNOBOL)!  Now **that** was an interesting programming course! Along with the one on [Simula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simula_67).

Ah the joys of studying at UNSW in the late '70's! (-:

Comment: 'sed' is a command for which plain '(' is not special but '\\(' is special; in contrast, PCRE reverses the sense, so '(' is special, but '\\(' is not.  This is exactly what the OP is asking about.

Comment: sed is a *nix utility that uses one of the most primitive sets of regexp evaluation. PCRE doesn't enter in to the situation I describes as it involves a different class of (in)finite automata with the way it evaluates regexps. I think my suggestion for the minimum set of regexp syntax still holds.

Comment: On a POSIX-compliant system, sed uses POSIX BRE, which I cover in my answer.  The GNU version on modern Linux system uses POSIX BRE with a few extensions.

Answer (score 4):

https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Quoting-metacharacters and https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html

In the official documentation, such characters are called metacharacters. Example of quoting:

```
my $regex = quotemeta($string);
s/$regex/something/
```

Answer (score 2):

For PHP, "it is always safe to precede a non-alphanumeric with "\" to specify that it stands for itself." - http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php.

Except if it's a " or '.  :/

To escape regex pattern variables (or partial variables) in PHP use preg_quote()

Answer (score 2):

To know when and what to escape without attempts is necessary to understand precisely the chain of contexts the string pass through. You will specify the string from the farthest side to its final destination which is the memory handled by the regexp parsing code.

Be aware how the string in memory is processed: if can be a plain string inside the code, or a string entered to the command line, but a could be either an interactive command line or a command line stated inside a shell script file, or inside a variable in memory mentioned by the code, or an (string)argument through further evaluation, or a string containing code generated dynamically with any sort of encapsulation...

Each of this context assigned some characters with special functionality.

When you want to pass the character literally without using its special function (local to the context), than that's the case you have to escape it, for the next context... which might need some other escape characters which might additionally need to be escaped in the preceding context(s).
Furthermore there can be things like character encoding (the most insidious is utf-8 because it look like ASCII for common characters, but might be optionally interpreted even by the terminal depending on its settings so it might behave differently, then the encoding attribute of HTML/XML, it's necessary to understand the process precisely right.

E.g. A regexp in the command line starting with `perl -npe`, needs to be transferred to a set of *exec* system calls connecting as pipe the file handles, each of this exec system calls just has a list of arguments that were separated by (non escaped)spaces, and possibly pipes(|) and redirection (> N> N>&M), parenthesis, interactive expansion of `*` and `?`, `$(())` ... (all this are special characters used by the *sh which might appear to interfere with the character of the regular expression in the next context, but they are evaluated in order: before the command line. The command line is read by a program as bash/sh/csh/tcsh/zsh, essentially inside double quote or single quote the escape is simpler but it is not necessary to quote a string in the command line because mostly the space has to be prefixed with backslash and the quote are not necessary leaving available the expand functionality for characters * and ?, but this parse as different context as within quote. Then when the command line is evaluated the regexp obtained in memory (not as written in the command line) receives the same treatment as it would be in a source file.
For regexp there is character-set context within square brackets [ ], perl regular expression can be quoted by a large set of non alfa-numeric characters (E.g. m// or m:/better/for/path: ...).

You have more details about characters in other answer, which are very specific to the final regexp context. As I noted you mention that you find the regexp escape with attempts, that's probably because different context has different set of character that confused your memory of attempts (often backslash is the character used in those different context to escape a literal character instead of its function).

Answer (score 1):

to avoid having to worry about which `regex` variant and all the bespoke peculiarties, just use this generic function that covers every `regex` variant other than `BRE` (unless they have unicode multi-byte chars that are meta) :

```
jot -s '' -c - 32 126 |
```

> ```
> mawk '
> function ___(__,_) {
>     return substr(_="", 
>     gsub("[][!-/_\140:-@{-~]","[&]",__),
>     gsub("["(_="\\\\")"^]",_ "&",__))__ 
>
> } ($++NF = ___($!_))^_'
> ```

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?
@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_
`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

> 

```
    [!]["][#][$][%][&]['][(][)][*][+][,][-][.][/]
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 [:][;][<][=][>][?]
 [@] ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ   [[]\\ []]\^ [_]
 [`] abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz   [{][|][}][~]
```

square-brackets are ***much*** easier to deal with, since there's no risk of triggering warning messages about "escaping too much", e.g. :

```
function ____(_) {
    return substr("", gsub("[[:punct:]]","\\\\&",_))_ 
} 

                     \!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/ 0123456789\:\;\<\=\>\?
\@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\[\\\]\^\_\`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz \{\|\}\~

gawk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp escape sequence `\!' is not a known regexp operator
gawk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp escape sequence `\"' is not a known regexp operator
gawk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp escape sequence `\#' is not a known regexp operator
gawk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp escape sequence `\%' is not a known regexp operator
gawk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp escape sequence `\&' is not a known regexp operator
gawk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp escape sequence `\,' is not a known regexp operator
gawk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp escape sequence `\:' is not a known regexp operator
gawk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp escape sequence `\;' is not a known regexp operator
gawk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp escape sequence `\=' is not a known regexp operator
gawk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp escape sequence `\@' is not a known regexp operator
gawk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp escape sequence `\_' is not a known regexp operator
gawk: cmd. line:1: warning: regexp escape sequence `\~' is not a known regexp operator
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

Works (backslash or quote all non-alphanumeric characters except underscore):

```
~$ raku -e 'say $/ if "#.*?" ~~ m/  \# \. \* \?  /; #works fine'
｢#.*?｣
```

There exist six flavors of Regular Expression languages, according to Damian Conway's pdf/talk ["Everything You Know About Regexes Is Wrong"](https://youtu.be/ubvSjW6Nyqk). Raku represents a significant (~15 year) re-working of standard Perl(5)/PCRE Regular Expressions.

In those 15 years the Perl_6 / Raku language experts decided that ***all non-alphanumeric characters (except underscore) shall be reserved as Regex metacharacters even if no present usage exists.*** To denote non-alphanumeric characters (except underscore) as literals, backslash or escape them.

So the above example prints the `$/` match variable if a match to a literal `#.*?` character sequence is found. Below is what happens if you don't: `#` is interpreted as the start of a comment, `.` dot is interpreted as any character (including whitespace), `*` asterisk is interpreted as a zero-or-more quantifier, and `?` question mark is interpreted as either a zero-or-one quantifier or a frugal (i.e. non-greedy) quantifier-modifier (depending on context):

Errors:

```
~$ ~$ raku -e 'say $/ if "#.*?" ~~ m/  # . * ?  /; #ERROR!'
===SORRY!===
Regex not terminated.
at -e:1
------> y $/ if "#.*?" ~~ m/ # . * ?  /; #ERROR!⏏<EOL>
Regex not terminated.
at -e:1
------> y $/ if "#.*?" ~~ m/ # . * ?  /; #ERROR!⏏<EOL>
Couldn't find terminator / (corresponding / was at line 1)
at -e:1
------> y $/ if "#.*?" ~~ m/ # . * ?  /; #ERROR!⏏<EOL>
    expecting any of:
        /
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org/

Answer (score 0):

For Ionic (Typescript) you have to double slash in order to scape the characters.
For example (this is to match some special characters):

```
"^(?=.*[\\]\\[!¡\'=ªº\\-\\_ç@#$%^&*(),;\\.?\":{}|<>\+\\/])"
```

Pay attention to this `] [ - _ . /` characters. They have to be double slashed. If you don't do that, you are going to have a type error in your code.